# Way to Reset Varible After Collision Resolution

Tags: collision-resolution, game-maker-dnd

I have some code that, if a player is in contact with the wall, prevents the player from moving.
[image: Code]
[image: Other code]

Is there any way with this code to reset the collide variable, and if not, what would be the simplest alternative.I have tried resting it at the start of the step but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing a different approach to this question.

Assign a `place_meeting` with some X and Y distance so if your object gets close to the wall, its speeds are reduced to 0, but far from that place, its speed continues to work. Something like:

```
if (place_meeting(x-3,y,obj_wall)) {
   x +=0
}
else {
   speed (variable) = speed
}
```

Another suggestion for you to try like this:

```
if ((keyboard_check(vk_down)) AND 
     NOT place_meeting (x,y+4(choose a good distance compared to the sprite), obj_wall))
{
   y +=4
}
```

The meaning: if you press the key and you are not close to the object it will move. It works in all directions.

Comment: I tried this but I found once they reached the wall, they could not move away from the wall.